# MS project - Show calendar exception name on gantt

Tags: ms-project

is there a way to show a calendar exception name when viewing a gantt chart ?

[image]

Comment: I need a bit more information... I can't tell what the picture is showing, and I'm not sure what a "calendar exception name" is...

Comment: THX for your reply, Tom Boyle answered on Nov 8 at 17:25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Project does not allow that functionality.  The shaded areas of the Gantt chart (depicted in your figure) represent non-working time of the calendar that is selected in the "Non-working time" tab of the Timescale window.  There is no other customization allowed beyond selection of the calendar.  (Typically only a small portion of this non-working time comes from exceptions anyway, as night-time and weekends are not exceptions.)

Others have tried to address the same need by drawing text boxes in the Gantt chart area or by including explicit Tasks (and corresponding bars) to identify specific non-working time.
Good luck, tom